# Update part of a page in jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I'm trying to make a search and send back the result to the same site, I've got the search to work but I can't get the result to be sent back. I want the start site to render the information without page reload.

How can I send the search result back to the index.jade page without having to update it?

```
function pagelist(items, res) {
    var document='';
    var db = db_login;
    if ( items != null){
            items.forEach(function(item) {
            document += '<a href=share/'+item._id+' class="searchElement">'
            document += item.document 
            document += '</div>'
        })
        if(document != ''){
            res.send(document);
        }else{
        }
    }
}
```

index.jade

```
extends layout
block content
    block child
```

child.jade

```
extends index
block child
    !{document}
```

Comment: are you using jade on the client as well, or only on the server? If not, you'd have to include it there, too. Or you could render the results to html on the server and then set it on the client through .innerHTML = value

Comment: no on the client as well

Comment: Then, why is your pagelist function sending back html? Are you planning to change it to sending back JSON?

Comment: true, I didn't this about that

Comment: but that wouldn't solve this problem right

Comment: No, but if you're already sending html back, why not just inserting it at the position of the document you want it, and completely forget about jade?

Comment: yes thats what im trying to. but i cant get it right, i dont know how to send information to a div from node.js. any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

You can do it the following way:

First, you could update your `index.jade` like this:

```
extends layout
block content
    #content
        block child
```

And then, there should be some sort of function you call to get your results. I'll call it `getResults`.
In the callback of that function you can now do the following:

```
getResults(function(results){
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = results;
});
```

I hope that helps.

**UPDATE**

I'll give you a complete example:

**server.js**

```
var express = require("express");

var i = 0;
function getResults(cb){
    cb("<div>Result "+(i++)+"</div><div>Result "+(i++)+"</div><div>Result "+(i++)+"</div>");
}

var app = express();
app.set("view engine","jade");
app.get("/",function(req,res){
    getResults(function(results){   
        res.render("page",{results:results});
    });
});
app.get("/results",function(req,res){
    getResults(function(results){       
        res.writeHead(200,"OK",{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
        res.end(results);
    });
});

app.listen(80);
```

**views/page.jade**

```
doctype html
html
    head
        script.
            function update(){
                var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                req.open("GET","/results");
                req.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(req.readyState == 4){
                        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = req.responseText;
                    }
                }
                req.send();
            }
    body
        #content!= results
        input(type="button",value="Update",onclick="update()")
```

Run it with `node server.js` and visit localhost. You should learn from it how it's done ;)

Comment: this is what i want to do, the thing is i have to do it from server side and i dont know how to send the information to clientside without updating the site.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. You cannot update your client from the server. The client must update itself with data it requests from the server. You have to to an XMLHttpRequest from the client to the server, that loads the data. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: ...you do know, how to execute JavaScript on the client-side right?

Comment: yes as long as i can access the data on the clientside i be fine,:)

Comment: are you using a routing framework, for example express? I'll have to make you a full example I think.