# what callback function should i use in an XMLHttpRequest to render the response?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

After a user does something on a page, I use ajax to send some data to my Node.js Express server. That server then does this:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res){
//user authentication then, inside that callback
  res.redirect('/dashboard');
}
```

dashboard.js then does this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("dashboard"); //<--This code is running
    res.render('index',{title:"You are logged in"});
}
```

Now the front end is doing this:

```
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback){
        let user = document.getElementById('username').value;
        let pass = document.getElementById('password').value;
        let data = {
            "username": user,
            "password": pass
        }
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
                callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
        xmlHttp.open("POST", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        var dataAsJson = JSON.stringify(data);
        xmlHttp.send(dataAsJson);
    }
```

Instead of seeing my nice "You are logged in" page, index.html logs to my browser's console. This is obviously because my onclick listener does this:

```
onclick='httpGetAsync("/createUser", console.log)'
```

Instead of `console.log` (which is obviously the wrong thing here), what should I be calling?

How do I get this `res.render('index',{title:"You are logged in"})` in dashboard.js to actually render?

This is a lot like [ExpressJS : res.redirect() not working as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202075/expressjs-res-redirect-not-working-as-expected), but that question does not include the portion that includes their front end code which is where I think the problem lies. And the last comment there reads: "No, never figured it out. I ended up building my app differently, with the login part in a modal, instead of another page... Very frustrating".

Comment: Do I need to write some replaceDocumentWith function?

Comment: Yes, your server should return only the elements that need to be changed, and then use something like `(res) => { document.getElementById("responseArea").innerHTML = res; }` for the callback instead of `console.log`.

Comment: document.write maybe?

Comment: [No!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/1048572) It doesn't work asynchronously anyway.

Comment: you can send `url` instead of `res.redirect` and @ client you can redirect to that url

Comment: LOL @Bergi No it didn't work.

Comment: It would be nice to just modify my innerHTML, but I'm using the Jade template language so all of my templates include tags like <html> which doesn't seem to fit into innerHTML.

Comment: Seems like I want to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626249/update-part-of-a-page-in-jade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `XHR` are meant to send and revive response you are receiving html page as response with status 301 or 302, the possible solution is to send the redirect `url` as response instead

```
router.post('/', function(req, res){
  //user authentication then, inside that callback
  res.send('/dashboard');
}
```

and on receiving this response you can redirect to response url on callback

```
function redirect(res){
  window.location = res;
}
```

`onclick='httpGetAsync("/createUser", redirect)'`

Comment: This seems promising, but it seems that redirect is not defined.

Comment: did you defined `redirect` function @ client ?

Comment: I should have noticed that. Thanks.